# Azure Keyvault access policy not working when deployed

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

I may be misunderstanding the Azure Auth flow, I am currently using the SecretClient for keyvault to retrieve and set secrets.

```
_client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

When working locally I can access and deny access using keyvault access policy on my user account although once deployed this no longer works

```
Error : SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication failed: Persistence check failed
```

The application uses Microsoft Identity to log the user in.

```
 services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

How do I replicate what I am seeing work successfully locally when I deploy the same code to the app service?

Comment: Have you assigned access permissions to this managed identity?

Comment: Do you want keyvault access to be permissioned to the user or to the application? If your app is an Azure App Service it is easiest to permission the app by turn on the managed identity and adding an access policy for it in the keyvault.

Comment: It is not a managed Identity, I will investigate using a user-managed-identity and see what I can find @GauravMantri.

Comment: @Crowcoder it is user, not application

Comment: And it is the same user account which worked locally?

Comment: Well then you need to [obtain a token on behalf of the user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/security-features#key-vault-authentication-options) to make the request to keyvault. It doesn't happen automatically just because they are logged to your application.

Comment: @GauravMantri, it did indeed. When i remove permissions I can see the access change in the local application but once deployed this is no longer the case.

Comment: "User" managed identity does not mean the identity is a user, it means a user manages it instead of the system.

Comment: @Crowcoder, yeah just realised that reading the docs. Your comment about obtaining the token on behalf seems like exactly what I need. You dont by chance know any example code resources for this? I am reading the docs at the moment

Comment: @MarcC sorry, no sample available. Of the 3 types of authentication I've only done the other two.

Comment: @Crowcoder fair enough, ill see what I can dig up. Appreciate it, any findings ill come back and answer the question